# ElasticSearch - added extra query option

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I made elasticsearch(version 5.1) query from java.

It just tried to find document that maching with field string.

```
boolQuery.filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("field", "test"));
```

When being converted as es json query, it added extra things.

> 'boost', 'disable_coord', 'adjust_pure_negative'

```
"query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "filter" : [
        {
          "term" : {
            "field" : {
              "value" : "test",
              "boost" : 1.0
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "disable_coord" : false,
      "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  }
```

Do I need boost event if I'm not going to use score information?
What are rest of tham and how to take them out from query?

Comment: Those are the defaults for those attributes anyway. And Elasticsearch client is adding them by default. That's normal.

Comment: Where can I get reference relative to this option?

Comment: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v5.1.1/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/BoolQueryBuilder.java#L51-L52 and https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v5.1.1/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/AbstractQueryBuilder.java#L53

Comment: could you post your answer? so I can flag this question as completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the defaults for those attributes anyway. And Elasticsearch client is adding them by default.

Relevant references:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v5.1.1/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/BoolQueryBuilder.java#L51-L52
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v5.1.1/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/AbstractQueryBuilder.java#L53

Comment: I just upgrade my ES to 6.3.0 (from 1.4.3). I'm using the elasticsearch_dsl for python and having the same issue. Just want to make sure it has no impact on the caching mechanism, because my new cluster cache is much smaller and I suspect this boost addition. Does filter cache ignore this boost value as well?